# Wordpress: choose which sizes will be generated while uploading the image

Tags: wordpress

I am using custom image sizes crop during uploading to WordPress. As you can see below, there are two categories (A and B are reflected in the names below). They are different in ratio. Some images will be used only within category A, and others within B. Every time I upload any image, all sizes are being created, even if I won't ever use them. Is there a way of choosing which sizes I want specific images to be loaded to?

For example, on the specific page, I will use only images from the category A and on others only B. I don't want to generate hundreds of images which will never be used. Is there a way to overcome this? Ideally without using any plugins, as I want to keep the code as clean as possible.

So generally speaking, I don't want unused sizes to be uploaded to the folder on the server.
Thank you

The code below is within functions.php

```
add_image_size('img-a-sm', 300, 200, true); 
add_image_size('img-a-md', 600, 400, true); 

add_image_size('img-b-sm', 300, 50, true); 
add_image_size('img-b-lg', 600, 100, true);
```

Can I choose which sizes will be generated while uploading the file?